# History of Underdetermined Interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

Are there any examples, earlier than spline-interpolation, of mathematical investigations of interpolation problems with more unknowns than conditions or are (polynomial) splines the earliest?

Spline interpolation deals with the fact that the continuity- and smoothness constraints are not sufficient for uniqueness by enforcing uniqueness by adding further conditions.

I haven't however seen the linear-algebraic solution of resorting to pseudo-inverses being utilized.

So my questions is what kind of solutions had been/are utilized since when for dealing with underdetermined interpolation; there seems to be an [increased interest in undetermined interpolation](https://www.mat.uc.pt/~lnv/papers/csv2.pdf).